# Is SP signing certificate mandatory in setting up trust

Tags: saml-2.0, idp

I have a basic question on setting up trust between a SP and IDP.

Usually a two way trust is required when we setup an IDP with SP by uploading certificates on either side.

Is signing certificate from SP mandatory to be configured in the IDP side ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1):

The defined [SAML 2.0 specifications](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) doesn't mandate that the request is signed.

> 4.1.3.3 <AuthnRequest> Is Issued by Service Provider to Identity Provider
>
> ...The <AuthnRequest> message MAY be signed, if authentication of the request issuer is required.

You can check with your Identity Provider documentation, but for example, [Microsoft Azure AD does not validate signed requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#signature), and there's no way to upload a request signing certificate.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a signing keypair on the SP side if you send the `subject` in the `AuthnRequest,` and your IdP utilizes the information when provided. If your SP isn't sending the `subject` attribute or your IdP won't consume it, you don't need it.